# Weird parse in C++: int f(int(arg)) equivalent to int f(int arg) - can anyone explain it?

Tags: c++

This was discovered by one of my coworkers when trying to construct an object with a single argument like this:

```
char testString[] = "test string";
...
MyClass instance(QString(testString));
```

They were aware of the situation where if you construct in the function-style idiom with a single argument it will be parsed as a forward-declared function, e.g.

```
char test[] = "hello";

MyClass instance1(0, test) //constructs an object
MyClass instance2(test) //invalidly forward-declares a function
```

but they were stumped by what they thought should work as it contained a function-style cast, or single-argument constructor invocation, inside the brackets.

I have since figured out that their constructor call was getting parsed like:

```
MyClass instance(QString testString);
```

Instead of passing in the variable testString to the cast operator, it declares a function with a parameter of the same name. My question is, why does it do that? It seems to be allowing the name of the parameter to be surrounded by brackets.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo nope. That's why this question is here.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo no, it isn't. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: You seem to have a problem with the brackets around the parameter name. Why shouldn't it allow that?

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ: I would say it shouldn't allow that because most people who look at it the first time expect it to be a declaration of an object, which is a perfectly reasonable expectation. Why *should* it allow it?

Comment: BTW this problem partially motivated uniform initalization syntax `MyClass instance(QString{testString});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, and in C, declarators may be surrounded by any number of parentheses:

```
int a;
int (b);
int ((c));
int f(int (x));
```

This is mainly useful to differentiate function pointer declarators from declarators of functions that return pointer types. For example, here `f` is a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`:

```
int (*f)(int x);
```

In other words, `(*f)(x)` is an `int` if `x` is an `int`. Whereas here, `f` is a function that takes an `int` and returns a pointer to an `int`:

```
int *f(int x);
```

In other words, `*f(x)` is an `int` if `x` is an `int`.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much the rationale. It extends to references in C++, too; consider: `void foo(int (&array)[5]) {}`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yep. Although unfortunately references break with the C idea that declaration mirror use; `int &x` does not mean that `&x` is an `int`.

Comment: That old idea was messed up anyway. It led to a horrific declarator syntax and generations of confusion for newbies learning pointers. Conventionally we do not think like that in C++ any more (`int& x` means that `x` is an `int&` tyvm), except in the edge cases wherein we must (like this one).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah, hah, it didn’t exactly pan out. On the other hand, having tutored CS, I found that beginners understood declarator syntax much more readily when I explained it in terms of how it’s defined, rather than in terms of types (with which they had little familiarity anyway). And then C++ comes along and introduces gratuitous complexity that makes neither interpretation strictly correct. Sigh.

Comment: Having tutored CS, I found the exact opposite lol (and do to this day)

Answer (score 8):

> This was discovered by one of my coworkers

No, it was "discovered" decades ago and is an extremely famous quirk of the language.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

> My question is, why does it do that? It seems to be allowing the name of the parameter to be surrounded by brackets.

It is. The C declaration syntax is not so prescriptive as to disallow this specific case. In the general case, it's useful for more complex constructions like this:

```
void foo(int (*func)(char));
// (takes a pointer to a function returning int and taking char, bool)

// as opposed to:
void foo(int *func(char));
// (takes a function returning int* and taking char)

// as this is literally equivalent to the clearer:
void foo(int* func(char));
```

and, in C++:

```
void foo(int (&array)[5]) {}
// (takes a reference to an array of five integers)

// as opposed to:
void foo(int &array[5]) {}
// (takes an array of five `int&`s ... and fails to compile accordingly)
```

Here is the admittedly unwieldy solution for your specific case:

```
MyClass instance((QString(testString)));
//               ^                   ^
```

or, more helpfully since C++11:

```
MyClass instance(QString{testString});
//                      ^          ^
```

This was in fact one of the driving factors behind introducing uniform initialisation syntax.

---

### Addendum

> if you construct in the function-style idiom with a single argument it will be parsed as a forward-declared function, e.g.
>
> ```
> MyClass instance2("hello") //invalidly forward-declares a function
> ```

This claim is simply untrue.

Also, `char *testString = "test string";` has been deprecated for 17 years and illegal for 4.

Comment: LOL +1 for the first part of the first sentence.

Comment: The question is not about the most vexing parse.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Yes, it is.

Comment: `MyClass instance(QString{testString});` could be even better solution?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What I mean is that the OP acknowledged this is an instance of the most vexing parse, but the actual question was *why* this notation is permitted in the first place.

Comment: @JonPurdy: I thought I might as well retread that ground, since the OP's example of an MVP was nothing of the sort.